# Show an operator is compact if $\sum \|Te_n\| < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

> Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space, define a bounded linear operator
>   $T:H \rightarrow H$, show it is compact if $\sum \|Te_n\|_H < \infty$.

**My attempt:**

We show that $T(B)$ is totally bounded.

For each $h\in B$ the unit ball, we have
$$\|h\| = \bigg\|\sum_{n=1}^\infty h_n e_n \bigg\| = \sum_{n=1}^\infty h_n^2 = 1$$
Let $\epsilon >0$ be given, there exists an $N$ such that
$$\sum_{n=N}^\infty \|Te_n\| <\epsilon/2.$$

Define 
$$T_N (h) = \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} h_n Te_n$$
and we see that 
$$\|T(h) - T_N(h)\| = \bigg\|\sum_{n=N}^\infty h_n Te_n\bigg\| \leq \sum_{n=N}^\infty \|Te_n\|\leq \epsilon/2 .$$
**(I am not sure about the above inequality)**

Then since $T_N(B)$ is finite dimensional, it is totally bounded, it can be covered with finite many balls with radius $\epsilon/2$. Since we have shown 
$$\|T(h) - T_N(h)\| \leq \epsilon/2,$$
expand each ball's radius from $\epsilon/2$ to $\epsilon$, the finite collection will cover $T(B)$.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think it's true. Limit of finite rank operators is always compact. Why are you not sure about that inequality @Xiao?

Comment: @FeliceIandoli what do you mean by limit of finite rank operator is always compact, could you explain please. I haven't done a lot of problems in Hilbert space, so I am not so sure about the connection between $e_n$ and $Te_n$ in general. thank you!

Comment: A finite rank operator is just an operator which image is finite-dimensional. If you have an operator $T:H\rightarrow H$ and a sequence of finite rank operators $T_n: H\rightarrow H$ such that $\| T-T_n\|_{\mathcal{L}(H)}\rightarrow 0$ then $T$ is a compact operator.

Comment: The proof, i think, it's similar to the one you gave above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $T_{N}h = \sum_{n=1}^{N}h_{n}Te_{n}$. Because $\sum_{n}\|Te_{n}\| < \infty$, then there is a constant $M$ such that $\|Te_{n}\| \le M$, or $\|Te_{n}\|^{1/2} \le M^{1/2}$ for all $n \ge 1$. Then you use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to get what you want:
$$
\begin{align}
         \|T_{N}h-Th\| & \le \sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|h_{n}|\|Te_{n}\| \\
           & \le M^{1/2}\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|h_{n}|\|Te_{n}\|^{1/2} \\
           & \le M^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}|h_{n}|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\|Te_{n}\|\right)^{1/2} \\
           & \le M^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=N+1}^{\infty}\|Te_{n}\|\right)^{1/2}\|h\|.
\end{align}
$$
This inequality gives you a uniform approximation of $T$ by a finite rank operator $T_{N}$, with
$$
           \|T_{N}-T\|^{2} \le M\sum_{n=N+1}\|Te_{n}\|.
$$